# Retrieve property from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

**Update: This code just works :) Other logic in my page caused a problem**

I'm reading out a JavaScript object from a jQuery data object:

```
$('body').data('myvals', {var1:"lorem",var2:"ipsum",var3:"dolores",var4:"amet"});
var obj = $('body').data('myvals');
```

I can successfully access the contents of this object

```
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

This returns (in Firefox console):

```
[["var1", "lorem"], ["var2", "ipsum"], ["var3", "dolores"], ["var4", "amet"]]
```

But I don't succeed in retrieving a specific property (getting 'lorem' by accessing 'var1'). Following attempts return `undefined`:

```
console.log(obj.var1);
console.log(obj[var1]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the structure of the `obj`.

Comment: Use `Object.keys` not `values`

Comment: I have Chrome Beta v52 and it still hasn't got the values method of Object. If you want a little standardization please use a Map object and values.. or use Object.keys.

Comment: @Redu it should support as we can [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @AlonEitan Care to show how to use Object.keys. Tried it, same problem.

Comment: Also post compele code, there is no way Object.values can return what you claim it returns.

Comment: @dfsq I just added the complete code.

Comment: @dfsq why not possible?

Comment: Because it's not how Object.values works. `Object.values({var1:"lorem",var2:"ipsum",var3:"dolores",var4:"amet"})` would give you `["lorem", "ipsum", "dolores", "amet"]`.

Comment: @bart Not after you've edited your question - I thought you're trying to access the object based on the result of `Object.values` (The `obj.var1` was the one got me confused)

Comment: You are looking for something like `Object.entries()` https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Anyway, define what input you have and what result you want, then you would have a good answer. Otherwise people are just guessing the solution.

Comment: @dfsq Just did, refresh page please.

Comment: @Redu Im using Object.entries() in my sample code above.

Comment: Okay. And what do you expect to get back?

Comment: @dfsq What do you think this will return: `Object.values({"a":["var1", "lorem"],"b":["var2", "ipsum"]})`?

Comment: @skobaljic This is not the point. I'm saying is that OP claimed that he had `Object.values({var1:"lorem",var2:"ipsum",var3:"dolores",var4:"amet"})` and the result was `[["var1", "lorem"], ["var2", "ipsum"], ["var3", "dolores"], ["var4", "amet"]]`. Now turned out he is using `entries` not `values`.

Comment: He never claimed that.

Comment: @dfsq I've edited the question, so yes, was using values before, not entries.

Comment: @dfsq Question is simple, how can I get 'lorem' back from the object?

Comment: Just after `var obj = $('body').data('myvals');` go with `console.log( obj.var1 );` [check it](https://jsfiddle.net/aj5bw4oo/)

Comment: @skobaljic That's exactly what doesn't work.

Comment: it works man, please check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
[["var1", "lorem"], ["var2", "ipsum"], ["var3", "dolores"], ["var4", "amet"]]
```

is an array with indexes as keys.Its is not an Object (Even though in Javascript pretty much everything is an Object) So when you try obj.var1 you will get undefined.
Cause there is no obj.var1 in there. There is obj[0] which holds array("var1", "lorem"); inside it.

This :

```
{"var1":"lorem"}, {"var2":"ipsum"},{"var3":"dolores"},{"var4":"amet"}
```

is an Object , in this one if you type console.log(obj.var1) you will get "lorem".

You added more code since i replied so i knopw need to change my annswer.
Your issue is "**Object.entries()**" , this will return an **Array** , you need to use

```
Object.keys(obj) .forEach(function(key){
 console.log(key);
});
```

**Addition**
Your question layout and provided info have been a bit confusing. 
Avoiding what you wrote at the start and focusing only on your last addition to your question  , your only error is the:

```
console.log(obj[var1]);
```

it should be

```
console.log(obj["var1"]);
```

Other than that it should work as expected.

Comment: I get it's not an object, but an array with indexes. Question remains, how do I get a value out of it?

Comment: I still don't get how I can retrieve 'lorem' using Object.keys

Answer (score 0):

this works just fine, I don't see what's the problem: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/021uj5xf/)**

```
$('body').data('myvals', {var1:"lorem",var2:"ipsum",var3:"dolores",var4:"amet"});
var obj = $('body').data('myvals');
console.log(obj.var1);
console.log(obj['var1']);
```

if the code above doesn't work try `console.log($('body').data('myvals'));` and see if it returns any value.

if it returns undefined then you've probably forgotten to use document ready, just try wrapping your code in `$(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Given that .entries shows the entries successfully, document ready can't be the problem.

Comment: entries is a pure javascript function, you need document ready for jQuery functions

Answer (score 0):

You can access the entries returned as pairs from `Object.entries` using destructuring as below:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
})
```

An alternative way to iterate using `for-of` loop

```js
let obj = { one: 1, two: 2 };
for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);
}
```

Comment: I know I can, but doesn't solve the problem. How do I get 'lorem' out of var1?

Comment: For that you can create a Map() and access the keys from the map. But you can't access the elements in an indexed sequence (Array) in linear order as you can do in Objects. So if your need is to access it as an object, you will need to convert it back to an object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing `Object.entries(obj)` to the console, it would be clearer for you to print the object itself to the console. The entry list is a distraction from the issue you're dealing with. What I mean is this:

```
var obj = $('body').data('myvals');
console.log(obj);

//or this
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

That will show you the actual content of the associative array. From there, either of these should work. Don't forget to use string quotes for the array index:

```
console.log(obj.var1);
console.log(obj["var1"]); // obj[var1] is incorrect, need quotes
```

If you see "var1" as a key in the full object printout above, then individual property should also be shown here. Otherwise, some other part of your code must have made changes to the content of `obj` or `$('body).data('myvals')` by the time you extract "var1"